# Convert Email Body to JSON object in an azure Function for my logic app

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

I have a logic app that whos trigger is on receiving emails. it passes my email body to the azure function. my function then takes the contents of the email and turns it into a json object for the rest of my logic app to use. [image]

[image]

currently if I hardcode the output for the JSON object in the azure function, all the steps complete fine. but when trying to read the email body data and return that as a json object it errors out with a 500 error

below is the code for my function

```
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
{

log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

string Name = req.Query["Name"];
string PhoneNumber = req.Query["PhoneNumber"];
string SSN = req.Query["SSN"];
string Email = req.Query["Email"];

string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
Name = Name ?? data?.Name;
PhoneNumber = PhoneNumber ?? data?.PhoneNumber;
SSN = SSN ?? data?.SSN;
Email = Email ?? data?.Email;

var myObj = new {name = Name, phone = PhoneNumber, ssn = SSN, email = Email};
var jsonToReturn = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myObj);

return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK) {
    Content = new StringContent(jsonToReturn, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
};
```

my sample mail body

```
  Name: LXXXXX ZXXXXXXXX
  PhoneNumber: 5XXXXXXXXX
  SSN: 1XXX
  Email: test@test.com
```

Comment: Your "sample mail body" isn't well-formed JSON.  Upload it to https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ and you will see many errors.  You won't be able to deserialize such a `requestBody` with a JSON serializer such as Json.NET.

Comment: Hi Lajos, may I know if the solution can solve your problem ?

Comment: Yes his solution helped to solve this

Comment: @LajosZadravecz As the solution works, could you please mark my answer as "accepted", thanks~

Answer (score 1):

The problem caused by the format of the body of "When a new email arrived" trigger, we can see the body shows as below:

[image]

It is not a json data, so when you send it to your function, it will fail.

So if you want to run your function success, we need to provide a well-formed data to your function. If you can decide the format of the email, modify it to the format as below:

```
"Name": "LXXXXX ZXXXXXXXX",
"PhoneNumber": "5XXXXXXXXX",
"SSN": "1XXX",
"Email": "test@test.com"
```

Then use [Html to text](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/conversionservice/#html-to-text) action to remove the html tag in the body from the email trigger.
[image]

After that, add the `{` and `}` at the beginning and the end of the data. And parse the json data.

[image]

Now you can use the body from parse json as the input of your function.